# Objective C: Keep task running at sleep mode IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, file-upload, background

I have an app which uploads videos to a server, the app is working well, also it keeps uploading at background, but when the user locks/sleep the iPhone, my background task stops running, I have been reading similar questions and the people response was: "it cant be achieved", "you cant" (but these answers were from two years ago). Is there a way to keep data uploading after device is locked/slept?

My app is based on Apple's SimpleFTPSample using `NSURLconnection`
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: How are you doing the upload now?

Comment: Use `NSURLSession` with `[NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:]`. That is the most robust way to perform background uploads and downloads.

Comment: http://corsarus.com/2015/background-fetching-using-nsurlsession/

Comment: Hi guys, thank you, i'm using `NSURLconnection` [edited question], is there a way to achieve the purpose using `NSURLconnection`? or is simple to change it to `NSURLSession`?